# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$POST_' (T_VARIABLE) at an INSERT statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm rather new with sql statements in PHP and got following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$POST_' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /home/u544596746/public_html/cobrahd/register.php on line 19

I looked the error up on the Internet, but only found other guys with the same problem for other code.

I would be happy if you could solve my problem.

```
<?php

        define('DB_HOST', '****');
        define('DB_NAME', '****');
        define('DB_USER','****');
        define('DB_PASSWORD','****');


        $con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
        $db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

        function register()
        {

            session_start();
            if($_POST["email"]!="" and $_POST["password"]!="" and $_POST["username"]!="" and $_POST["password"]== $_POST["password_confirm"])
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUser`(`UserName`, `Vorname`, `Nachname`, `EMail`, `Geschlecht`, `Geburtsdatum`, `RegestrierungDate`, `Password`, `FKRole`) VALUES ('" .$POST_['username']. "','"$POST_['vorname']. "','" .$POST_['nachname']. "','" .$POST_['email']. "','" .$POST_['geschlecht']. "','" .$POST_['geburtsdatum']. "',Curdate(),'" .$POST_['password']. "',2)";
                echo $sql;

                header('Location: index.php');
            }
            else
            {
                header('Location: 404.html');
            }
        }
        if(isset    ($_POST['submit']))
        {
            register();
        }


    ?>
```

Comment: You have `$POST_` instead of `$_POST`. Also have a look at [sql injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) and how to prevent it.

Comment: Also, please improve the formatting of your question.

Comment: The MySQL function has been removed, please don't use that anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the:

```
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUser`(`UserName`, `Vorname`, `Nachname`, `EMail`, `Geschlecht`, `Geburtsdatum`, `RegestrierungDate`, `Password`, `FKRole`) VALUES ('" .$POST_['username']. "','"$POST_['vorname']. "','" .$POST_['nachname']. "','" .$POST_['email']. "','" .$POST_['geschlecht']. "','" .$POST_['geburtsdatum']. "',Curdate(),'" .$POST_['password']. "',2)";
            echo $sql;
```

to this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUser`(`UserName`, `Vorname`, `Nachname`, `EMail`, `Geschlecht`, `Geburtsdatum`, `RegestrierungDate`, `Password`, `FKRole`) VALUES ('" .$_POST['username']. "','"$_POST['vorname']. "','" .$_POST['nachname']. "','" .$_POST['email']. "','" .$_POST['geschlecht']. "','" .$_POST['geburtsdatum']. "',Curdate(),'" .$_POST['password']. "',2)";
                echo $sql;
```

there are typographic errors in your code. you are writing `POST_` instead of `_POST`. And also you `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_` it is deprecated.

EDIT:

There was another error:

you didn't concatenated correctly. Use following

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUser`(`UserName`, `Vorname`, `Nachname`, `EMail`, `Geschlecht`, `Geburtsdatum`, `RegestrierungDate`, `Password`, `FKRole`) VALUES ('" .$_POST['username']. "','" . $_POST['vorname']. "','" .$_POST['nachname']. "','" .$_POST['email']. "','" .$_POST['geschlecht']. "','" .$_POST['geburtsdatum']. "',Curdate(),'" .$_POST['password']. "',2)";
```

Comment: I see my mistake and changed it in the code. But now i get another 
Parse error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/u544596746/public_html/register.php on line 18

this is line 18:
```$sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUser`(`UserName`, `Vorname`, `Nachname`, `EMail`, `Geschlecht`, `Geburtsdatum`, `RegestrierungDate`, `Password`, `FKRole`) VALUES ('" .$_POST['username']. "','"$_POST['vorname']. "','" .$_POST['nachname']. "','" .$_POST['email']. "','" .$_POST['geschlecht']. "','" .$_POST['geburtsdatum']. "',Curdate(),'" .$_POST['password']. "',2)";```

Comment: @BenjaminPössenberger check edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$POST_
```

to

```
$_POST
```

The valid syntax is $_POST